# using expect shell script from php displays only the spawn command

Tags: php, expect

I'm using a php script that get arguments from a html page and send them to an expect shell.

When I call this php from CLI it works fine but when i call it from the web page it displays only the first line `spawn ssh user@host`

The code:

```
#!/bin/sh
var=$(expect -c "
spawn ssh user@host 
expect \"password:\"
send \"XXXX\r\"
expect -re \"prompt>\"
send \"./xx.sh $1 $2 $3\r\"
expect -re \"prompt>\"
send \"sleep 35\"
expect -re \"prompt>\"
send \"logout\"
")
echo "$var"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you write this as pure expect script. Saves resources (no extra sh process):

```
#/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh user@host
expect "password:"
send "XXXX\r"
expect -re "prompt>"
send "./xx.sh [join $argv]\r"
expect -re "prompt>"
send "sleep 35"
expect -re "prompt>"
send "logout"
```

The only changes here are the shebang and the `[join $argv]`. This will pass ALL parameters you pass to this expect script.

As next step I suggest adding a line with

```
exp_internal 1
```

after the shebang. This will output more, which helps to debug.

Comment: hi,i tried this but still same resuls. i only see the firslt line of the sciprt: spwan ssh user@host and thats it. when i run  it  from cli its ok.

Comment: I managed to connect and run the script but i can only see some of the result and not all of it, what can be the problem?

Comment: Just an other question: how do you call the script?

Comment: I used a php script to run another local sh script (expect) that runs another script on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and adding the following to the end of my expect script fixed it:

```
expect eof
exit
```